# Conjugacy classes in centralizers

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups

Let $G$ be a complex reductive group, let $g$ be an element, and let $C$ be the connected component of its centralizer. I'm curious about what is known about the intersection of conjugacy classes in $G$ with $C$.

For example, if $C$ is reductive, then a conjugacy class in $G$ intersects $C$ in a finite number of conjugacy classes.

In general, if two elements $k, h \in C$ are conjugate in $G$, when can we expect them to be conjugate in $C$? For example, does it help if we know in addition that $k$ is in the closure of the $C$-conjugacy class of $h$?

Comment: Since the centraliser of a semisimple element is reductive, and since the centraliser of $g$ is the centraliser in $\operatorname{Cent}_G(g_\text{semi})$ of $g_{\text{unip}}$, your question reduces to the case where $g$ is unipotent (but I don't know the answer there), at least "up to finite error".

Comment: In the case where $g$ is reductive, are the elements $k$ and $h$ as described above conjugate in $C$?

Comment: Not necessarily.  Consider the case where $g$ is regular semisimple, so that $C$-conjugacy is trivial, and $k$ and $h$ are Weyl-conjugate.  (But, in general, for $C$ reductive, the closure of the $C$-conjugacy class of $h$ is controlled by the semisimple part of $h$, so once again your closure condition reduces the problem to the case where $k$ and $h$ are unipotent.  In particular, your closure condition means that, if $g$, $k$, and $h$ are all semisimple, then $k$ and $h$ are $C$-conjugate.)

Comment: Oh I see. But in that case, if $C$-conjugacy classes are points, then $h = k$ because $k$ is in the closure of the conjugacy class of $h$. So the extra assumption seems to make an important difference.

Comment: [Yes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377978/conjugacy-classes-in-centralizers#comment959022_377978), it does.  Sorry, I [edited that in](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/377978/conjugacy-classes-in-centralizers#comment959021_377978) while you were responding.

Comment: This seems to indicate that the finitely many $C$-conjugacy classes when $C$ is reductive are disconnected, rather than being in each other's closure. So I guess my question (which I'm having a bit of trouble making precise) is whether this is the case (even when $C$ not reductive).

Comment: I think that your question with the closure condition is precise, and that the answer to that version may be 'yes' in general, but I do not know much about centralisers of unipotent elements.  I will think about it.

Comment: The explicit computation in terms of partitions of the closure ordering of unipotent orbits in classical groups shows that the result is true for $g$ semisimple and $G$ classical, but I still can't see how to prove it in general.